# How to migrate this from LiveData to Kotlin Flow on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I'm new to Kotlin Flow on Android.
Can you please tell me how I can migrate this LiveData code to Flow?

```
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val myRepository: MyRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val myData = MutableLiveData<Data?>(null)
    fun fetchData(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            myData.postValue(myRepository.fetchSuspend(query))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a `MutableStateFlow` instead of `MutableLiveData` to hold the data. A `StateFlow` is similar to a `LiveData` in that it emits updates to its observers.

```
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val myRepository: MyRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val _myData = MutableStateFlow<Data?>(null)
    val myData: StateFlow<Data?> 
        get() = _myData

    fun fetchData(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _myData.value = myRepository.fetchSuspend(query)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mikhail! A few questions: 1- Why use MutableStateFlow over MutableSharedFlow? What's the difference? 2- Can we use "emit" instead of setting "value"? 3- How do you observe "myData" in a Fragment?

Comment: You're welcome. 1- The main difference between a SharedFlow and a StateFlow is that a StateFlow takes a default value through the constructor and emits it immediately when someone starts collecting, while a SharedFlow takes no value and emits nothing by default. So StateFlow is an ideal option for display some state on the screen (for example text in TextView).  2 - yes, emit() is just a suspend function which sets a value under the hood. 3 - call StateFlow.collect() from a coroutine or some suspend function.